# Can't calculate total in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a total newbie in React and my problem is this: 
I have a component called 'IncExpSummary' which shows to total amount of income and expenses. It receives data of income and expenses from redux store by using 'mapStateToProps'. I also have a selector function called 'total' which map over the array of object and return total(this function is working fine). The problem is every time I add new income or expense the total is not calculated but the amount of new item is add at the end of previous number.

The IncExpSummary looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import total from '../selectors/total.js';

class IncExpSummary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="income-summary">
          <p className="income-summary-text">Income: {this.props.totalIncome}</p>

        </div>
        <div className="expense-summary">
          <p className="expense-summary-text">Expense: {this.props.totalExpense}</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProp(state) {
  return {
    totalIncome: total(state.income),
    totalExpense: total(state.expenses)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProp)(IncExpSummary);
```

The 'total' function looks like this:

```
export default (data) => {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    return data.map((item) => {
      return item.amount;
    }).reduce((total, amount) => {
      return total + amount;
    });
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

After adding two income with amount 30 and 20 each I expected the output to be 50, but the actual output is 3020.

Complete project is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4k6q6ok5q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `item.amount` values are strings. This results in the strings getting concatenated.

Change it to the following so the strings will be parsed as floats and it will work properly:

```js
export default (data) => {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    return data.map((item) => {
      return parseFloat(item.amount);
    }).reduce((total, amount) => {
      return total + amount;
    });
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: @sid-ubaid no problem, happy to help! Please accept it as answer to let people know your question has been answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse to a number:

```
export default (data) => {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    return data.map(({ amount }) => parseFloat(amount)).reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the line in the 'total' function from returning the string amount:

```
return item.amount;
```

to below for return integer amount:

```
return +item.amount;
```